# SSH to personal laptop from external pc

Tags: command-line, ssh

The process that I want is:

Connect by ssh to a pc1 from my laptop, in pc1 connect to pc2 and in pc2 connect to my laptop.

**How can I know which IP is my laptop?**

**Is that possible?**

Comment: Try `ip addr` on your laptop. Alternately, whatever same way you know the IP addresses of the other PCs.

Comment: @user68186 Yes, that analogy applies, sometimes is faster to send files from PC2 to my laptop than to walk back all the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise question you are asking is a little unclear to me, but I think what you are trying to do is very much possible. It sounds like you want to connect over the Internet, not just your local network. You'll want to first try getting it up and running locally, then work on connecting from outside. At a very high level, here are the basic steps:

1. First, **[install and configure an SSH
   server](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-enable-ssh-on-ubuntu-18-04/)**
   on any destination device.
2. To **find out the private IP and connect over your local network**,
   easiest would probably be to run `ifconfig` or `ip a` from the destination
   device. Alternatively, you might look at the leases on your router,
   or maybe even use a network scanner (such as
   [Fing](https://www.fing.com/products/fing-app) on an Android
   device).
3. At this point you're already able to connect from one device to another via SSH on your local network. If you're going to be doing this regularly and/or want to connect
   from outside, you'll want to **configure a static IP or DHCP
   reservation** either [on the destination server
   itself](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu),
   or on your router. It's generally easier to do this from the router in my opinion, but every router is different.
4. To connect from outside, at minimum you will need to set up [**port
   forwarding**](https://portforward.com/) on your router. Before doing this, make sure you have a very strong password on any account with SSH access (For more in security, see step 6.)
5. Now your ready to connect from an external network. You can simply
   [look up your public IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/) from a device
   at home and if port forwarding is configured correctly, that should
   work--until your IP changes. **To reliably find your public IP while
   remote, you'll probably want to have a public DNS name**.
   [No-IP](https://www.noip.com/) is a free and easy solution for this.
   Once you have that set up, you could simply SSH to
   "AnotherChemist.hopto.org" or whatever you manage to reserve.
6. The last point I will make is that if you do want to connect
   remotely, you need to **consider security**.
   [Here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/security/harden-ssh-server) is a
   good list of relevant tips. If at all possible, you really want to
   disable remote password logins and allow certificate-based logins
   only. At the very least, make sure you have a very strong password
   and put fail2ban in place. **Do this before you enable port
   forwarding for any significant amount of time.** Especially if you
   are on the default SSH port of 23, hackers around the world will
   literally start trying to brute force your password within a matter
   of minutes!